# Qt Application Deployment - libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found

Tags: linux, qt

I built my Application on Mint 13 and added all Qt Libraries following https://lemirep.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/deploying-qt-applications-on-linux-and-windows-3/

Now I would like to run my Application on Mint 17.2, but with gdb I get error:

> gdb: /home/vladimir/MyApplication/Qt_Libraries/libc.so.6: version
>   `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0)

But version of libc.so.6 is 2.19. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Open up the file "/home/vladimir/MyApplication/Qt_Libraries/libc.so.6" and grep for "GLIBC_2.17".. Most probably it shouldnt be there.. that is why you are getting the error. You needed to update your libc6 package to the latest. However, could you please tell me how you came to know you have 2.19.. ?